# Find a node in a the tree based on some selection criteria

Tags: algorithm

```
                 [BASE]
                 / \  \
                C1  C2 C3
                /\       \
               C4 C5      C6
```

I have a tree like the above. This is a N child tree which is not balanced. The problem is, I need to select one of the node based on some condition. Like

```
Select C1 when k1 = a
Select C4 when K1 = a and K2=b and K3=C
Select C5 when k1 = a and k'=z

Select C2 when K'' = b
Select C3 when k5 = 9
Select C6 when k5=9 and k6 = 10
```

The input to the program would be an arbitraty length of key value pairs like if input is  -`k1=a,k2=b,k3=c,k8=10`  - I should select `C4` as that is the best match.

Ideally I was thinking of traversing the tree and for each node, there is a selection criteria which I can match against the input set. But soon I figured out, this tree can be very huge and Base node can have tens of thousands of child nodes under it. So it might not be a good idea to go node by node. If there is a way to select the nodes more efficiently, I would love to know that.

Comment: Please explain your notation. Meaning of K and '?

Comment: Selection criteria for each node is defined in terms of key/value pairs which I was trying to describe as k1=a where k1 is the name of the key and 'a' is the value.

Comment: If a property holds at some node then the same property will hold for its children? I see no proper structure in this tree, based on what conditions is the tree build? How does it relates to key/value pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workable solution like this one

```
----------------------------------------
|rowId|param1|param2|param3|param4|node|
----------------------------------------
|10   | a   |      |      |      | C1  |
----------------------------------------
|14   | a   | b    |  c   |      | C4  |
----------------------------------------
|18   | a   | b    |      |      | C5  |
----------------------------------------
```

Lets call it a condition table. Each column represent the input series (k) and for different combinations of the value, there is a node to be selected. This table can be think of an in memory data structure or a real table in RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your k's are pointing to directory structure and the leaf of this structure (exactly one leaf for each directory) is the node you are looking for. You can keep this string in node as another value. What is not clear in question is how are the k's related to the tree 
for e.g.

```
a->c1
a/b/c->c4
```